# Make the image to stretch over full html body in Bootstrap page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/huhese/3)

The image is small in size but I need it to stretch over the full area. Without repeating.
How can it be done through CSS?
The page uses Bootstrap.

```
html{


 background:url("http://cdn7.oxygenna.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/custom-icon-note-800x600.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter care to comment>

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine it's the usual: where's your code? Linking to an external example can be helpful, but the relevant code should be here *first*. External code can change, go away, etc.

Comment: I still did not down-vote here but I suppose the problem is that you should include your code here, not just give as a hyperlink

Comment: got the point..have to say its d biggest mistake of my life

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect,but the image you have selected itself has a white border in it and the paper is in the center

crop the image properly and code will work for you